# Show all results count with limit?

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to show results, and show the number of all results, but I need to limit in 5 results to paginate. How I can do it? I use this query:

```
<?php
        $q = strtolower($_GET["CONTENT"]);
        $count = 0;
        $Read = new Read();
        $Read->FullRead("SELECT 
            CATEGORIES.CATEGORY_ID, 
            CATEGORIES.CATEGORY_COLOR, 
            LINKS.LINK_TITLE, 
            LINKS.LINK_ID, 
            LINKS.LINK_FRIENDLY_URL, 
            LINKS.LINK_CATEGORY, 
            LINKS.LINK_PHOTO, 
            LINKS.LINK_ID 
            FROM LINKS INNER JOIN CATEGORIES 
            ON 
            LINKS.LINK_CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.CATEGORY_ID 
            WHERE LINK_STATUS = 1 
            AND ROWNUM <= 5 
            AND regexp_like(LINKS.LINK_TITLE, '{$q}', 'i') ORDER BY LINK_DATE DESC");
        if ($Read->getResult()):
            foreach ($Read->getResult() as $LINK):
                extract($LINK);
        $count++;

endforeach;
endif;

echo $count;
?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you are only selecting five *random* rows (not literally random, but the first five in Oracle's internal bookkeeping which is not based on your ordering criteria). Always remember that the `ORDER BY` clause in a SQL statement is processed only **after** all the other clauses are already done, so your `ORDER BY` will have no effect on `ROWNUM` in the same query. By the time you get to `ORDER BY` the rows were already limited to just five.

To fix this, you need to do everything else in a subquery. Then select from the subquery and add `WHERE ROWNUM <= 5` in the outer query, not in the subquery.